# JQuery Ajax and Playframework - Status 0 ErrorText "" with one s in url

Tags: jquery, playframework-2.0

I'm using [playframework](http://www.playframework.com/) 2.1.1 with jquery 1.9.0, twitter bootstrap typeahead and underscore.js. My goal is to implement a simple auto-completion REST-service.

**Setup**

My routes file

```
GET   /api/search/autocomplete/:query   controllers.Autocomplete.complete(query)
```

My backend code returns a json list of strings.

My search.js implementation of the typeahead function.

```
$('form :text').typeahead({
    items: 15,
    matcher: function() { return true }, // turn off jquery intelligence

    // debounce would be really helpful here
    source:  function (query, process) {
        var load = jsRoutes.controllers.Autocomplete.complete(query).ajax({
            success: function(results) {
                process(results);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                return false;
            }
        });
        _.debounce(load, 250);
    }
});
```

**Problem**

If I call the url

> localhost:9000/api/search/autocomplete/s

everything works fine and I get a JSON back. However I call this URL with

> jsRoutes.controllers.Autocomplete.complete(query).ajax(...)

I get a "status:0". And only on the letter **b** !!

Answer (score 0):

It was some error in the BE code. However the error reporting of jquery was a bit weird. Sorry